# How to change ckeditor dialog default tab?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

the code is worked , but only work on first time

```
if (dialogName == 'image') {
    dialogDefinition.removeContents('upload');
    dialogDefinition.removeContents('advanced');
    dialogDefinition.removeContents('Link');

    var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');
    infoTab.remove('txtAlt');
    infoTab.remove('txtBorder');
    infoTab.remove('txtHSpace');
    infoTab.remove('txtVSpace');
    infoTab.remove('cmbAlign');

    dialogDefinition.onLoad = function () {
        this.selectPage('Upload');
    };
}
```

If I do not refresh  the page , click the "image" button twice not be "Upload". 
Need some help ,tks

Answer (score 0):

you can put this code in config.js:

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (ev) {
    // Take the dialog window name and its definition from the event data.
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
    if (dialogName == 'link') {
        dialogDefinition.removeContents('advanced'); //remove advanced tab

        var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');
        var urlField = infoTab.get('url');
        urlField['default'] = 'www.ireadhome.com'; //set default value for the url field
    }
});
```